# Convert a String to its integer type assigned value

Tags: vb.net

Using Below codes in VB.net, I have some variables (HUCROW1,HUCROW2,HUCROW3) which are integer type and a specific value is assigned to each of them.
Then in a loop I try to make HUCROW equal to above variables. HUCROW is string type and I concatenate it with the loop number for example by using "HUCROW" & 1.

```
                HUCROW1 = 66                
                HUCROW2 = 84                
                HUCROW3 = 102                
                HUCROW4 = 120


        For j = 1 To 3                
            Dim HUCROW As String = "HUCROW" & (j)


            If ScheduleSht.Cells(HUCROW, 9).Value.Ticks <> Nothing Then
                HUCdates(i) = ScheduleSht.Cells(HUCROW, 9).value.Ticks
                HUCdates(i) = ScheduleSht.Cells(HUCROW, 9).value.Ticks
            Else
                HUCdates(i) = 0
            End If

        Next
```

My aim is to get HUCROW1 value which is 66, but it doesn't work and give "type mismatch error" on ScheduleSht.Cells(HUCROW, 9).value.Ticks as it doesn't convert the string HUCROW to its assigned number.
Any help on how to convert the string type "HUCROW1" to the assigned integer value to HUCROW1 would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're using the Excel COM object-model. Is this VB.NET or VBA?

Comment: @Dai it is VB.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to use an array or a dictionary to store and retrive the values.

**Array sample** (subtract j because an array's index starts from zero)

```
Dim HUCROWS As Integer() = {66, 84, 102, 120}

For j = 1 To 3
    Console.WriteLine(HUCROWS(j - 1))
Next
```

**Dictionary sample**

```
Dim HUCROWS As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {
    {"HUCROW1", 66},
    {"HUCROW2", 84},
    {"HUCROW3", 102},
    {"HUCROW4", 120}
}

For j = 1 To 3
    Dim HUCROW As String = "HUCROW" & j
    Console.WriteLine(HUCROWS(HUCROW))
Next
```

**Result of both codes**

```
66
84
102
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting, I haven't used that dictionary type before. I'll give it a try.

Comment: A dictionary represents a collection of keys & values. So in this example, I create a dictionary with 4 pairs of keys & values. First pair's key is HUCROW1 and its value is 66. Second pair's key is HUCROW2 and its value is 84, and so on. When I need a value from a certain pair, I use the key to retrieve the value, eg. HUCROWS("HUCROW1") retrieves 66, while HUCROWS("HUCROW2") retrieves 84.

Comment: The dictionary is declared with 2 types. First type is the type of the key which is string in this code. Second type is the type of the value which is integer in this code.

Comment: Great, it Works.